# Differences between reboot, remake, reimagining - is my understanding correct?

Tags: production, terminology, continuity, reboot

I know that reboot is a term often used by the media to mean a comeback of a franchise from scratch, but is my understanding correct of the terms:

- **Reboot**: To start again from scratch, all previous continuity/canon is null and void.

  - **Hard reboot**: None of the previous continuity is canon any more - entirely new canon
  - **Soft reboot**: Some of the previous canon/characters/continuity carry over to the new movie, but not all. Partially new, partially related to previous continuity.
- **Remake**: Re-making the original film, with minimal or no changes.
- **Re-imagining**: Similar premise as the original but different in some ways (e.g. Christmas Carol films, The March Sisters at Christmas (a remake of Little Women, as I understand it).
- **Alternate continuity**: It's canon, but the continuity is different from the original. Not quite the same as a spin-off. (Transformers is about the best example I can think of, apart from Marvel/DC Comics).

Is my understanding correct?

I am aware that many film series can be continuity-heavy, e.g. Freddy vs Jason, Captain America etc.

Just checking to ensure my understanding is correct.

Comment: The question about how long a reboot typically lasts is a little too borad and largely unanswerable in a general sense, though, since that entirely depends on the specific film and seems to shrink further every year anyway.

Comment: And it's a dupe. The same question has been asked before.

Comment: @cde Where? Feel free to provide a link to that question and/or close-vote it as a duplicate.

Comment: I have removed the too broad part that asked for how long reboots last. In its current form it seems like a reasonable question. However, the majority of close-votes were already made before that ciritical part was removed. I'd thus ask the users to reconsider if this is still too broad and why.

Answer (score 4):

> Remake: Re-making the original film, with minimal or no changes.

I'd say this is wrong.  A remake carries the same general plot line, but is often very different from the original.  Just thinking of movies like [*Total Recall* (2012)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1386703/) or [*The Magnificent Seven* (2016)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2404435/) (which is, in fact, a "re-imagining" of [*Seven Samurai* (1954)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0047478/)) and they're very different from the original versions

**Reboots** are used for a series of films that will carry a storyline or characters across the series, as opposed to a **remake** which is the term used for a stand-alone film.

**Re-imagining** is when they loosely remake a movie, such as Seven Samurai/Magnificent Seven referenced above.  [*Robinson Crusoe On Mars* (1964)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0058530/) is another example of a re-imagining.